How to deploy Sitecore wdp zip files in Azure PaaS?
We have to install the Cumulative hotfixes on the existing Azure PaaS environment. Please suggest the different kind of steps to install on Sitecore XP scaled environments.

This is hard to say without knowing how you deploy. We deploy the hotfix as a module (like there are other modules - eg SXA).

To install the hotfix you can follow these steps by referring to the below article.

Create one separate project in your solution named SitecoreHotfix.Patch or any other name convenient for you

Add all the cumulative hotfix package files in the same project with the correct file or folder path.


Refer to the following articles describing how to install the hotfixes for OnPrem and PaaS instances.

Install a Sitecore XP pre-release using SIF
Deploy a Sitecore XP pre-release to a PaaS solution

Here you will get all the details of the benefits of creating a new project in your solution.
https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/05/sitecore-cumulative-hotfixes-installation-onprem-and-paas.html
Hope this helps.

To install a cumulative hotfix on a Sitecore XP scaled environment, follow these steps:
Create a Separate Project: In your solution, create a new project (e.g., SitecoreHotfix.Patch) and add all the hotfix package files with the correct paths.
Use Pre-Release Packages: Sitecore provides cumulative pre-release packages that include all previous changes. These can be requested from Sitecore Support.
Deployment Methods:

SIF (Sitecore Installation Framework): Deploy the Web Deployment Packages (WDP) using individual templates for each server role.
Azure ARM Templates: Provide the WDP package link inside the ARM template to deploy it in Azure.

For detailed guidance, refer to the official documentation:

Install a Sitecore XP pre-release using SIF

Deploy a Sitecore XP pre-release to PaaS


This approach ensures a smooth deployment of hotfixes in your environment.

Sitecore now provide pre-releases that are cumulative and includes all the changes that were implemented on the earlier releases. These pre-releases are available on request from Sitecore Customer Support.
Each pre-release contains the Web Deployment Packages(WDP) that you can deploy to update your Sitecore XP solution. These WDP packages can then installed to the scaled ennvironment using any of the below options.

SIF

Individual templates inside WDP files can be used to deploy to each server role. More details on the same can be found here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/install-a-sitecore-xp-pre-release-using-sif.html

Azure ARM Template

Inside the ARM templates, link to the wdp package needs to be provided. More details on the same can be found here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/deploy-a-sitecore-xp-pre-release-to-a-paas-solution.html
Using any of the above ways, you can deploy the cumulative hotfix on the Azure PAAS scaled environment.
Hope this helps!!!
